# Yii2 Form validation message with html

Tags: validation, yii2

when i try to add html to validation message i get:

```
E-mail is already in use.<a href="/site/request-password-reset/">Restore password</a>
```

how can i use html tags?

```
['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => ('E-mail is already in use.<a href="/site/request-password-reset/">Restore password</a>')],
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using ActiveForm. You have to set `encode` to `false`, else it will not work, as it defaults to `true`
Example code below:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'fieldConfig' => ['errorOptions' => ['encode' => false]] 
]);
```

?>